# Spring @async with multiple actions

Tags: java, spring

Here is my code :

**AsyncComponent.Java**

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncComponent {
@Autowired
    private AsyncService asyncService;

    @Async(value="campaignEmails")
    public void sendEmailsToContacts(Campaign campaign,EmailTemplate template,Set<User> uniqueUsers){
                asyncService.sendEmails(campaign, template, uniqueUsers);

    }
}
```

**AsyncService.java**

```
@Service("asyncService")
@Transactional
public class AsyncService {

private void sendEmailsToContacts(Campaign campaign,EmailTemplate template,Set<User> uniqueUsers){
Integer companyId = 1;
    for(User user:uniqueUsers){
            sendEmailsToContacts(campaign, template, companyId, user);          
        }
}

    private void sendEmailsToContacts2(Campaign campaign, EmailTemplate template, Integer companyId, User user){

        CampaignEmailsHistory history = new CampaignEmailsHistory();
        history.setCampaignId(campaign.getId());
        history.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        history.setSentTime(new Date());
        campaignDao.saveCampaignEmailsHistory(history); 

        mailService.sendMail("sending mail to user here");      


        logger.debug("Exit from sendEmailsToContacts() for ["+user.getEmailId()+"]**********("+campaign.getCampaign()+")");
        logger.debug("---------------------E N D---------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

When i'm using the above code, suppose if i have 5000 users then first 5000 users are receiving the emails and
Then
CampaignEmailsHistory is started inserting into the database.

Instead of this, first it should insert one record into the database and after inserting then only it should send one mail to one user. same way this should repeat for 5000 users.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have annotated the class with `@Transactional` which is equivalent to annotating each method of your class with `@Transactional`.

When `sendEmailsToContacts()` is invoked, a database transaction starts. And then, all the database insert statement are executed. When the method completes, the transaction is committed. Only after the transaction is committed, any changes made as part of that transaction are visible to other clients. If any error occurs during the execution of the method (ex: mail service throws an exception), all changes made to the database (record insertions) are rolled back.

If you want each insert to be done independently of the others, you can remove the `@Transactional` annotation on your class.